# How to make Font Awesome Icons solid when using Font Awesome 6 Pro

Tags: css, font-awesome, user-experience, font-awesome-6

I have the following pseudo-css rendering the correct Font-Awesome icons, but just not as solid icons:

```
content: "\f0dc";
font-family: 'Font Awesome 6 Pro';
padding-left: 5px;
font-weight: 900;
```

This renders the icons as "regular" =>  [image] not as solid icons.

What do I need to do to have these icons render as solid icons?

Comment: The solid icons are free, so you could just use 'Font Awesome 6 Free'. How are you loading them? Through a CDN?

Comment: Using 'Font Awesome 6 Free' gives me the empty box error and the icon doesn't load in.

Comment: How are you loading your icons? If you have a pro license it should include everything but there are CDNs that have everything packed in and just won't let you use anything pro (the blank box effect)https://jsfiddle.net/astombaugh/yj9adruk/7/

Comment: Not sure about the CDN, but from what I see, it looks like we load in the icons with the default as 'fa-regular', which is why I am getting that as the default in I load in an icon instead of the solid icon..

Comment: https://fontawesome.com/v5/docs/web/advanced/css-pseudo-elements you might want to take a look at this. I use the `<i>` versions in HTML rather than the pseudo-elements and it appears those are a little more complicated than just using the HTML such as `<i class="fa-solid fa-sort"></i>`

Comment: Which CSS file(s) are you loading? You won't be able to adjust the font weights unless you use either the all.css or solid.css files.

Comment: Thanks for the help everyone. Turns out we loaded in the fa-regular .css throughout our app. So, those are the only weights we can use unless I manually take the font-awesome svg and upload it to out site. We just went with the fa-regular option instead of working through getting the fa-solid to work.